# Passing a variable between callback and main

Tags: c++, class, boost, callback, shared-ptr

I'm using ROS with C++ and after receiving data from a topic in void callback(), I need to pass this data to a variable in int main(). What I've found out so far is that I can do it using a boost shared pointer and should use a "class in the program with callback as member function".
Part of my code so far:

```
double pos_z;
void callback(gazebo_msgs::LinkStates msgs_ls)
{
   double pos_z = msgs_ls.pose[43].position.z
   pos_z = pos_z + 1;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   ros::init(...);
   ros::Nodehandle n;
   ros::Subscriber ls_sub = n.subscribe("/gazebo/link_states", 10, callback);
   ros::ServiceClient sls_client = n.serviceClient<gazebo_msgs::SetLinkState>("/gazebo/set_link_state");
   gazebo_msgs::SetLinkState setLinkState;
   while (ros::ok))
   {
      setLinkState.request.link_state.position.z = pos_z;
      sls_client.call(setLinkState);
  }
```

About the shared pointer: this could be `boost::shared_ptr<double> a_ptr(&a, noop_delete` with `auto noop_delete = [](double *){}` but I don't really understand how to implement this. Also the mentioned class with callback as member function is unclear to me. Examples show implementations using C, and I don't know if I can use that.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: adding auto noop_deleter = [](double *){} as a global declaration and boost::shared_ptr<double> z_ptr(&z, noop_deleter) in main. I need this in the callback as well, probably as an argument like double*, but that doesn't compile. as for the class in the code with callback, I don't know how to start except for maybe class{void callback} but that is all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advice you were given is good :

> use a "class in the program with callback as member function"

You do it like that :

```
class SuperCoolRobot {
public:
  SuperCoolRobot ():pos_z(0) {
    // Note : we provide the callback (a member) + a state (this)
    ls_sub = n.subscribe("/gazebo/link_states", 10, SuperCoolRobot::link_state_callback, this);
  }

  void link_state_callback(gazebo_msgs::LinkStates msgs_ls) {
    pos_z = msgs_ls.pose[43].position.z + 1;
  }

  void run() {
    gazebo_msgs::SetLinkState setLinkState;
    while (ros::ok))
    {
      setLinkState.request.link_state.position.z = pos_z;
      sls_client.call(setLinkState);
    }
  }
protected:
  // state here
  ros::Nodehandle n;
  ros::Subscriber ls_sub;
  double pos_z;
};
```

Then the main :

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  SuperCoolRobot robot;
  robot.run();
}
```

Note that I don't know ROS so I just threw what I understood from your code. Ajust it of course.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Question: subscribe can't have "this" as an argument. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: @user2294285 That's strange, the ROS documentation says it can : http://www.ros.org/doc/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#a317fe4c05919e0bf3fb5162ccb2f7c28

Comment: OK, I've searched the link, but I don't find "this" as an argument. Could you tell which subscribe version ?

Comment: `this` is a special value : a pointer on the current object (`SuperCoolRobot*` in this case). "this" is used as the 4th param of the `subscribe` function, which expect `T* obj` with "T" meaning "any type". The 3rd param is a member method of a T obj with a specific signature, which is exactly what our `link_state_callback(...)` is.

Comment: I understand that. What I notice is that, as soon as I add `this` as 4th param of the `subscribe` function, my IDE (Eclipse) shows that `subscribe` has an error. So apparently there is something not quite right.

Comment: @user2294285 Eclipse is not always true : Eclipse checks for errors with a custom C++ parser written in Java. Compile it, the compiler will tell you the truth. Or maybe your ROS version is not the same as the doc I looked at...

Comment: compiling ends with: `error: no matching function for call to 'ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const char [20], int, <unresolved overloaded function type>, Pera* const)'`

Comment: I should add that I compile on commandline, not inside Eclipse.

Comment: Got it working; there was an & missing. Thank you both very much for helping.

Comment: If you mean to up-vote; I already tried to do that, but it's not accepted for some reason. Says "vote up requires 15 reputation". BTW, other problem showing up: I put prints in-between and it appears that callback isn't called at all. I suspect a * or & missing in callback(..) but haven't figured out what and how yet.

Comment: @user2294285 there should be a transparent "tick" below the downvote button. Click it and it will turn green. Thanks !

Comment: Done so. Still figuring out the missing `*` or `&` somewhere/somehow in `void callback(gazebo_msgs::LinkStates msgs_ls)`...